# Why my links inside iFrame oEmbed doesn't work in Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, oembed

Thank you for reading my question!

I've been struggling with this WordPress oEmbed issue for a few days and tried everything I can.

**Issue:** When I put oEmbed link in my Wordpress post article, the iFrame card renders properly, but somehow the links inside the embedded content don't do anything when I click them.

Here's the iframe output code. I noticed there are several attributes for security settings.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" data-secret="zMkRyFvhFL" width="600" height="200" title="“【バハマ 】アトランティス 水族館の徹底解説” — サチーズのブログ" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" data-src="https://sachiese.com/atlantis-aquariums-lagoons/embed/#?secret=zMkRyFvhFL" class="wp-embedded-content lazyloaded" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="><noscript><iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);" src="https://sachiese.com/atlantis-aquariums-lagoons/embed/#?secret=zMkRyFvhFL" data-secret="zMkRyFvhFL" width="600" height="338" title="&#8220;【バハマ 】アトランティス 水族館の徹底解説&#8221; &#8212; サチーズのブログ" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></noscript></iframe>
```

and the link `<a>` tags are output like this

```
<a href="https://sachiese.com/atlantis-aquariums-lagoons/" target="_top">【バハマ 】アトランティス 水族館の徹底解説</a>
```

**Environment:**
Wordpress Version: 4.9.13 (I've not updated for a while as I don't like the new Wordpress feature)

Page URL: https://sachiese.com/bahamas-atlantis-hotel-resort/

**What I've tried so far**

- Changing the theme => no change
- Removing `sandbox` and `security` attributes in the Chrome developer tool => no change
- Tried other links for embed (Youtube page) => All the links work perfectly
- Checked my server security setting => Cannot find any outstanding item that affects (as far as I can tell)
- Try oEmbed with other WP website I have under same server. => Works

I'd appreciate your help! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the `LazyLoad` feature on `iframe` by checking if off from the `Media Types` field on the plugin setting panel. 
Now the oEmbed link works perfectly! :D

Comment: What plugin are you referring to that you had to change the settings on?